# How to access local virtualhost from container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have local development with virtualhost, without docker, let say `some.test` without docker.

This is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ./
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    network_mode: host
    extra_hosts:
      - "some.test:127.0.0.1"
```

I want to access it from docker container, i tried with curl but i got connection refused.

Comment: What URL are you trying to call?  Is the configuration you show for the client, or the server, or both?  This Compose setup includes several options that seem to work around normal Docker isolation features; if this setup works without Docker, what benefits are you hoping to get by adding it?

Comment: https://dev.magento2.test, yes it's show for the client, if i call host.docker.internal it works, but it's not pointing to that url

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your local development server is running and accessible on your host machine at `http://some.test`. You can verify this by accessing `http://some.test` in your host machine's browser.

Update your `docker-compose.yml` file to include a `port` mapping from the container to the host. For example, if your local development server is running on port 80, you can add the following line under the app service:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ./
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    ports:
      - 80:80
    extra_hosts:
      - "some.test:127.0.0.1"
```

Comment: Not working, Error response from daemon: invalid IP address in add-host: "host.docker.internal"

Comment: i think exposing port 80 is not gonna work, because it's already in use

Comment: If port 80 is already in use on your host machine, you can choose a different host port to map to port 80 inside the Docker container.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, NubDev! Many or most of your 23 answers in the last two weeks appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. 

We do hope you'll stick around and become a valuable part of our community by posting *your own* quality content. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.